# Split Menu in two

Tags: 7, routes, navigation

I'm trying to create a page where the main menu will be a horizontal nav structure, but split into two groups of links so that I can have a logo in the centre of the nav menu and half the links either side of it.

Has anyone done this with Drupal? Any ideas on how it would be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a link to the home page, move it to the middle and then grab it with CSS to show the logo as background image, hide text and space out the left and right sides.

Check out also [Menu Icons](http://drupal.org/project/menu_icons) which allows you to upload images for menu items.